# Mongo DB specify date query for all subobjects

Tags: mongodb

I'm still new to MongoDB and I'm not able to achieve the following.
This a object inside one of the collections I have to deal with:

```
 {
     "_id" : ObjectId("5306ad28e4b04bd6667b03bf"),
     "name" : "FOOBAR",
     "Items" : [
         {
             "price" : 0,
             "currency" : "EUR",
             "expiryDate" : ISODate("2014-03-15T23:00:00Z"),
         },
         {
             "price" : 0,
             "currency" : "EUR",
             "expiryDate" : ISODate("2015-03-15T23:00:00Z"),
         },
         {
             "currency" : "EUR",
             "expiryDate" : ISODate("2015-04-16T23:00:00Z"),
         }, ...}
```

I now need to find objects, where the timestamp "expiryDate" for all sub-objects inside "Items" is less than a certain value (ISODate).

Here's what it tried:

```
1. first try

db.COLL.findOne({"Items.expiryDate": { $lt : ISODate("2015-02-10T00:00:00.000Z") }}));"
```

This will also return object where only one "expiryDate" is less thane.

2. second try

   ```
   db.COLL.findOne({"Items": { $all : [ "$elemMatch" : { expiryDate: { $lt: ISODate(\"2015-02-10T00:00:00.000Z\") }} ] }}));"
   ```

Every query gives me only items where *some* but not *all* subobjects have a timestamp less than a certain time.

Please help me write this query!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/applications/aggregation/)** to achieve this.

Using the [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator we can find the size of `Items` which will be used in the later stages of aggregation. 
The [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) deconstructs the `Items` array so that we can apply the condition on individual items in the next [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage.

In the [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage we calculate the size of filtered `Items` and compare it with the original `size` using [`$cmp`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/) operator.This is done to identify documents where all sub-documents are less than the `Date` supplied in the `$match` condition.'

```
db.Coll.aggregate([
    {'$project': {'name': 1, 'size': {'$size': '$Items'},'Items': 1}},
    {'$unwind': '$Items'},
    {'$match':  {'Items.expiryDate': { $lt: ISODate("2015-03-15T23:40:00.000Z")}}},
    {'$group': { '_id': '$_id','Items': { '$push': '$Items'},'size':{'$first': '$size'}, 'newsize': {'$sum':1}}},
    {'$project': {'cmp_value': { $cmp : ['$size', '$newsize']},'name' :1 ,'Items': 1}},
    {'$match': {'cmp_value': 0}}
])
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and let it run for a while. I just think the data I want to "unwind" is too big and can not be handeled by mongo.

Comment: You can put a  `$match` before `$unwind` to reduce the data for the next stage in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's very old question, let me write my comment for others.

> db.collection.findOne

will return only one record. Instead you should use

> db.collection.find

Hope this helps!